# How to use 2 objects in an sObject list

Tags: apex, visualforce, list

I need to use fields from 2 different custom objects in a VF page `apex:pageBlockTable`. How can I use a List  to put 2 objects in a single list?

```
public List<Recipient__c> recList{
    get {
      if(recList== null)
         recList = new List<Recipient__c>
      return recList; 
   }
    set;
}


public List<Scholarship_Award__c> schList{
    get {
      if(schList== null)
         schList= new List<Scholarship_Award__c>
      return schList; 
   }
    set;
}

//sObject list for all objects

public sObject[] getAllRecords() {
  sObject[] results = new sObject[0];
  results.addAll(recList);
  results.addAll(schList);
  return results;
}
//Empty constructor - DML not allowed in constructor
public awardsClass(){
    
}

//Add recipient row in pageBlockTable
public PageReference add_recipient(){
    
    //insert scholarship award

    
    Recipient__c anotherRecipient = new Recipient__c();
    anotherRecipient.Name = rec.Name;
    anotherRecipient.Last_Name__c = rec.Last_Name__c;
    anotherRecipient.School__c = rec.School__c;
    anotherRecipient.Specialty__c = rec.Specialty__c;
    anotherRecipient.Biography__c = rec.Biography__c;   
    
    sch.Recipient__c = rec.Id;
    upsert sch;
    results.add(anotherRecipient);
    return null;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You may need to add more information here to get a clear answer. Your purpose might be achievable just by traversing schema relationships, or you may need to work with a wrapper class.

Comment: Try casting to an SObject or Object and adding to a List of the respective type (i,e. List<Object> or List<SObject>). This similar post may help if I understand what you are asking here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175113/pros-and-cons-of-generic-sobject-list-vs-multiple-lists-of-objects

Comment: Created lists for both objects and added it to an `<sObject>` list successfully. But it is returning the error `Unknown property sObject.Name()`

Answer (score 2):

If they need to be in the same variable, use `sObject` instead:

```
public List<sObject> allrecords {
    get {
      if(allrecords == null)
         allrecords = new List<sObject>();
      return allrecords; 
   }
    set;
}
```

If you need two separate variables, then you can just use two variables.

---

To combine the list based on updates, use a getter method:

```
public sObject[] getAllRecords() {
  sObject[] results = new sObject[0];
  results.addAll(recList);
  results.addAll(schList);
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks so much. Do I define both objects in  `sObject` ?

Comment: Please see updated code

Comment: @patriciajlim This list would only update once. You need to use a getter *method* instead.

Comment: Would this replace `List<sObject>`? I've updated my code, but I don't think I understand properly.

Comment: @patriciajlim Yes, you'd use getAllRecords instead of the property.

Comment: Thank you. It is returning the error: `Unknown property: sObject.Name` when using the above code - I have tried using wrapper class lists for this purpose, but they cannot be inserted due to the DML.